# Why 2 versions of Jetty Maven plugins?

Tags: jetty, maven-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin

I set up a new webapp Maven project and wanted to test it with Jetty's Maven plugin.
So I issued the console command: `mvn jetty:run`

After defining the `pluginGroup` in Maven's settings file I ran once again the command.
Unfortunately, it failed because I was using one of the below mentioned versions of the plugin:

- [maven-jetty-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)
- [jetty-maven-plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin)

Why are there 2 Maven based plugins for achieving the same thing - running Jetty? Why do they have to bring so much confusion?

Or be so kind as to explain me the differences between them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Jetty7 this plugin was renamed to jetty-maven-plugin to better conform to maven2 convention. The Jetty 7 version of the plugin has also undergone substantial changes in configuration. For more information, see the Jetty 7 Maven Plugin feature guide.

See the docs [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin)

Answer (score 7):

The `maven-jetty-plugin` is for Jetty 6 and `jetty-maven-plugin` is for Jetty7 and later. The name change was made to "adhere with maven plugin naming conventions" and is part of the big mess created by the move of Jetty to the Eclipse Foundation. Actually, Jetty 7 is considered as a transition version (this must be the politically correct expression for *big mess*).